# How to set a value in a reference field programmatically?

Tags: 7, commerce, entities

I have installed Drupal Commerce in an existing site and I use a Product reference field to attach items from the web shop to each existing product in the site.
Since there are more than 1 000 items in the site, I would like to avoid doing this manually.

So I thought I could use `hook_node_view` in a custom module and the rows below to check if the Product reference field is empty. If so I could just fetch the value from the old existing SKU field (`field_artikelnummer`) and set it to the new Product reference field (`field_add_to_cart`), in order to create the connection between the existing product node and the product in the Drupal commerce (imported by Feeds).

So I have come up with this:

```
  if($node->type === "instrument"){
    $node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
    $referenced_product = !empty($node_wrapper->field_add_to_cart->value()) ?   $node_wrapper->field_field_add_to_cart->value() : NULL;
    dsm($references_product->sku);
    if(empty($references_product->sku)){ // if there is no product reference
      $item_sku = $node_wrapper->field_artikelnummer->raw(); // get the existing old sku value from the existing node
      dsm($item_sku);
          /* and then how do I set $item_sku in the Product reference field? */
      $node_wrapper->save();
    }
```

EDITED:

Finally I found this solution using `commerce_product_load_by_sku()`:

```
  if($node->type === "instrument"){
    $node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
    $referenced_product = !empty($node_wrapper->field_add_to_cart->value()) ?   $node_wrapper->field_field_add_to_cart->value() : NULL;
    dsm($references_product->sku);
    if(empty($references_product->sku)){ // if there is no product reference
      $item_sku = $node_wrapper->field_artikelnummer->raw();
      $ref_new_product = commerce_product_load_by_sku($item_sku);
      $new_product_id = $ref_new_product->product_id;
      $node_wrapper->field_lagg_i_varukorgen->set($new_product_id);
      $node_wrapper->save();
    }
```

This actually connects the existing nodes to the imported products in drupal commerce. BUT, I need to refresh each page twice in order to get it to work. I tried to add node_save($node) as a last row, but that gave me a bunch of error messages like these:

```
Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! i DrupalDefaultEntityController->load() (rad 175 av C:\wamp\www\includes\entity.inc).
Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! i DrupalDefaultEntityController->cacheGet() (rad 388 av C:\wamp\www\includes\entity.inc).
```

Comment: is there anything rendering inside `dsm($references_product->sku);`

Comment: No, you are right. I was probably too tired at that moment... But I did found how to set the value. See above. Still need to figure one or two things out though,